# How to configure comet (comet.ml) to create pull requests on GitHub?

Tags: github, keras, comet-ml

Ive followed this this to link my comet.ml project to GitHub - [link](https://github.com/comet-ml/comet-quickstart-guide/blob/master/github-pullrequest/README.md)

and had some models already trained (using keras)in my project

[image]

Ive linked my GitHub account and when creating a pull request I get error

**Cant create pull request**

[image]

please advise

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have linked your Comet ML project to GitHub **after** you ran / trained your models.

for Comet ML to track code and create pull requests you must link your project **before** you train models using comet.ml.

see the full Comet ML and GitHub [docs](https://github.com/comet-ml/comet-quickstart-guide/blob/master/github-pullrequest/README.md)